# Installing busybox for ubuntu

Tags: debian, busybox, initramfs

I'm trying to create an initramfs for ubuntu using [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs) guide. How do I "re-create" the `USE="static" emerge -av busybox`command on ubuntu, as emerge is gentoo-specific command?

Basically, what are the steps to install a functioning busybox on ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a static linked `busybox` binary in any Debian derivate distribution, you run:

```
sudo apt-get install busybox-static
```

> busybox-static provides you with a statically linked simple stand
>   alone shell that provides all the utilities available in BusyBox. This
>   package is intended to be used as a rescue shell, in the event that
>   you screw up your system. Invoke "busybox sh" and you have a
>   standalone shell ready to save your system from certain destruction.
>   Invoke "busybox", and it will list the available builtin commands.

PS. `busybox-static` has its uses. Just be aware the binary is the double of the size of the regular `busybox`. You might have to adjust *slightly* your `/boot` partition size if it is on the small side.

Comment: I compared sizes of /bin/busybox from two different packages in Ubuntu:
busybox             719728
busybox-static 2065728  i.e. 2017Kb and has additional applets: crond, crontab, dpkg, dpkg-deb, ed, fdisk, passwd, static-sh, tc, su, sulogin, telnetd, tunctl

busybox-static is installed by default in Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu the package manager is called APT.

```
$ sudo apt-get install busybox
```

To search for packages:

```
$ apt-get search busybox
```

**NOTE:** You can also use the executable `apt` instead.

Comment: `apt` and `apt-get` are different programs with different purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update. I generally use Redhat, not so much w/ the Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: @slm I am more used to Debian, and going RH now at the new job.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - Yeah we primarily use CentOS 6/7. I use Fedora/CentOS/Ubuntu/Raspian at home. I have a Debian VM that I bring up when I'm trying to answer a Q here, but otherwise, Raspian/Ubuntu is as close as I get.