# cURL url_effective with Hash

Tags: shell-script, command-line, curl

If you put this link in a browser:

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453740#453743
```

it returns this:

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453740/installing-busybox-for-ubuntu#453743
```

However cURL drops the Hash:

```
$ curl -I https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453740#453743
HTTP/2 302
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
location: /questions/453740/installing-busybox-for-ubuntu
```

Does cURL have an option to keep the Hash with the resultant URL? Essentially I
am trying to write a script that will resolve URLs like a browser - this is what
I have so far but it breaks if the URL contains a Hash:

```
$ set https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453740#453743
$ curl -L -s -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$1"
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453740/installing-busybox-for-ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl download **whole** pages.
A `#` points to a **fragment**.

Both are not compatible.

---

## hash

The symbol `#` is used at the end of a web page link to mark a position inside a whole web page.

- [Fragment URLs](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#h-4.1.1)

  > ...convention called "fragment URLs" to refer to anchors within an HTML document.
- [What is it when a link has a pound "#" sign in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2800195/9110606)

  > It's a "fragment" or "named anchor". You can you use to link to part of a document.
- [Wikipedia: Uniform Resource Locator (URL)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

  > An optional fragment component preceded by an hash (#). The fragment contains a fragment identifier providing direction to a secondary resource, such as a section heading in an article identified by the remainder of the URI. When the primary resource is an HTML document, the fragment is often an id attribute of a specific element, and web browsers will scroll this element into view.

Its main use is to move the "presentation layer" (what is viewed) to the start of an item.

## curl

There is no "presentation layer" in curl, its goal is to download whole pages, not parts or fragments of pages. Therefore, there is no use for a "fragment" marker in curl. It is simply ignored by curl.

## Workaround

Re-append the tag to the (redirected) link:

```
originallink='https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453740#453743'
wholepage=$(curl -Lso /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$originallink")
if [ "$originallink" != "${originallink##*#}" ]; then
    newlink=$wholepage#${originallink##*#}
else
    echo "link contains no segment"
    newlink="$wholepage"
fi
    echo "$newlink"
```

Will print:

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453740/installing-busybox-for-ubuntu#453743
```

A quite faster solution is to not download the page. It is being redirected to `/dev/null` anyway. By removing the `-L` option and asking what would be the link if the (first) redirect were followed. The first redirect works in this case and most others.

```
wholepage=$(curl -so /dev/null -w %{redirect_url} "$originallink")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread on the `curl` website titled: [Re: How to send fragment part of URL?](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2011-11/0179.html) the hashmark is meant for the browser and not the server, hence why `curl` is truncating it.

> The fragment part of a URI is not meant to be sent in the HTTP request - it is 
>   used to identify a specific section in the resource that will be fetched by 
>   using the particular URI. If you want to force #-letter into the request I 
>   think encoding it sounds like a perfect idea.

Looking I did not see any method for `curl` to persist it beyond encoding it as `%23`, which I don't think is what you want.

#### Solution

Since it's the client that's maintaining the string after the hashmark, I'd "lean into it" and simply parse it out and then re-append it to the returned URL from `curl` as a true browser client would do it:

```
$ set 'https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453740#453743'
$ echo "$(curl -I -L -s -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} "$1")#$(echo "$1" | cut -d"#" -f2)"
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453740/installing-busybox-for-ubuntu#453743
```

#### References

- [Wget with URL that contains #](https://superuser.com/questions/487323/wget-with-url-that-contains)

Comment: I would be fine with encoding - but i dont think it works in this case - it just 404s

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm seeing with it as well.